# How to store distinct characters of a string

Tags: java, string

```
public class NoDuplicate { 
    static final int NO_OF_CHARS = 256; 
       
    /* Print duplicates present in the passed string */
    static void printDistinct(String str) 
    { 
        // Create an array of size 256 and count of 
        // every character in it 
        int[] count = new int[NO_OF_CHARS]; 
       
        /* Count array with frequency of characters */
        int i; 
        for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
            if(str.charAt(i)!=' ') 
                count[(int)str.charAt(i)]++; 
        int n = i; 
       
        // Print characters having count more than 0 
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            if (count[(int)str.charAt(i)] == 1) 
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i)); 
    } 
       
    /* Driver program*/
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String str = "SHINCHAN"; 
        printDistinct(str); 
    } 
}
```

I am trying to store the distinct characters in a string. The problem is that my code remove all duplicate elements. Example:

> Input: `SHINCHAN`
>
> Actual output: `SICA`
>
> Desired output: `SHINCA` (I want to store each element once)

Comment: @ShivamSharma - Why not change your algorithm to run on the string, letter by letter, and save it. Before adding a letter to the string, check to see if it already exists. If it doesn't, add it. If it does - don't.

Comment: Comment `// Print characters having count more than 0`: that would be the correct thing to do.   The actual code `if (count[(int)str.charAt(i)] == 1) ...` doesn't do that.  You actually _counted_ the characters correctly; the problem is all on the output side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a `LinkedHashSet` to implement the same :

```
static void printDistinct(String str) {
    Set<Character> origSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
    StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (origSet.add(str.charAt(i))) {
            concat.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(concat);
}
```

---

If you are using java-8, you can just do :

```
str.chars().mapToObj(e -> Character.toString((char) e))
           .distinct()
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nicholas but Output is returning in the set form

Comment: Instead of printing out the *Set*, you can iterate over it and then print the elements :) Something like this will work : `origSet.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: can I store it in a some string variable ? @Nicholas K

Comment: 1) Since *Set* doesn't have a get method you can't do `origSet.get(i)` 2) Use a *StringBuilder* instead of *String*. So now while adding the element to the *Set* you can do : `Set<Character> origSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
  StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   if (origSet.add(str.charAt(i))) {
    concat.append(str.charAt(i));
   }
  }` This will work because the `add()` returns a `boolean` value

Answer (score 3):

```
static void printDistinct(String str) {
        String s="";
        Set<Character> origSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            origSet.add(str.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(origSet);
        for(char c:origSet) {
            s=s+c;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

This code will store your string

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to print the characters in the first loop. Print them the first time you see them only. Then you can get rid of the second loop entirely.

```
/* Count array with frequency of characters */
int i; 
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i)!=' ') {
        count[(int)str.charAt(i)]++; 
        if (count[(int)str.charAt(i)] == 1) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, saving `str.charAt(i)` in a variable would make the code a bit nicer to read.

```
/* Count array with frequency of characters */
int i; 
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch != ' ') {
        count[(int) ch]++; 
        if (count[(int) ch] == 1) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }
}
```